# How to perform calculations on a dataset CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, sum, calculation

So I have a CSV file loaded in using read.csv like so:

```
data <- read.csv(file = 'data.csv', header=TRUE)
```

Which loads as:

```
label id length strength weakness 
 a    1    2        3        2    
 a    2    3        2        4    
 a    3    4        2        9    
 a    4    7        6        3
```

How would I go about performing some simple calculations on columns on a row-by-row basis?

For example, I wish to sum the strength + weakness / length for just a(1) but not a(2) or a(3), so each done as separate calculations for their respective rows.

If adding a new column for it makes it easier then that would work too, but also just printing the values works. I'm new to R and I've tried some simple rowSum/colSum combinations but I can't seem to figure this out for summing two columns but only for that respective row and not for all label/id's at once.

Appreciate any help with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `subset` the data required for calculation :

```
with(subset(data, label == 'a' & id == 1), strength + weakness / length)
```

This will perform the calculation only for rows where `label = 'a'` and `id = 1`.

If you want to write the result to new column, we can put the condition in `ifelse`.

```
transform(data, new_col = ifelse(label == 'a' & id == 1, 
                           strength + weakness / length, NA))
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! Would there be a way to write the result to a new column within the same row?